# $\operatorname{Dom}(f)$ countable $\rightarrow$ $\operatorname{Ran}(f)$ countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ a map, if $\:\operatorname{Dom}(f)$ is a countable set, show that $\operatorname{Ran}(f)$ is a countable set.

Comment: What is $X$? And $Y$? $f$ is any function?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ any sets and $f$ is any function

Comment: I am certain there are better duplicate targets. But this one will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is surjective onto its range.  Whenever you have a surjection from $X$ to $Y$, it follows that $\mid Y\mid\le\mid X\mid$.  (This is a basic fact from set theory.)

Comment: Not so basic. It uses the axiom of choice, which is unnecessary to this exercise.